# pandas with reading file

Tags: python, pandas, read.csv

I'm trying to read csv file stored in my computer using pandas.
This is my code, but I have a problem like the screenshot.

```
file_path = "/Users/shazelpark/laptop_pricing_dataset_mod1.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0)
```

I'd like to read the file without problem.
Please share your solutions.

Thanks

Comment: There is no screenshot in your question (copy/paste the full traceback of your error). Please provide a sample of your csv file `head -10 laptop_pricing_dataset_mod1.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = "/Users/shazelpark/laptop_pricing_dataset_mod1.csv"

try:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0)
    print(df.head())  
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found. Please check the file path.")
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
    print("The file appears to be empty.")
except pd.errors.ParserError:
    print("There was an issue parsing the file. Please check the file format.")
```